# Is it possible to make one post category unsearchable in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, categories

I have a category that I don't want to be searchable in my wordpress site. The category is for employees only. I have created a username and password on my site for them to access and also a simple rss feed web app to view it from their phones, but I need it to not be searchable on search engines. I have installed Wordpress Access Areas, but if I set the view post to "Logged in Users" the post disappears from the RSS feed.

Is there a code I can use to make sure that the posts aren't searchable but still able to show up in an rss feed for my employees?

Answer (score 1):

[`Simply Exclude`](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simply-exclude/) plugin will do what you are looking for :) You can filter which posts, categories, tags and other taxonomies are available to WordPress search.